# How to point Rails in `development` to a differently named DB config in `database.yml`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.6

The goal is to configure all 3 default environments ('development', 'test', 'production') from the `ENV` hash. **How can I tell Rails to establish the following mapping**, where `main` is defined in `config/database.yml` below?

```
'development' -> main
'test' -> main
'production' -> main
```

DB configs are consolidated to `main` in `config/database.yml` like so:

```yaml
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  port: 5432
  timeout: 10000

main:
  <<: *defaults
  url: <%= ENV['MAIN_DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['MAIN_DATABASE_POOL'] %>
```

In `:development` & `:test`, `gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]` loads the runtime env from `.env` files. In `:production` the ENV is set via other means.

Alas, when I do `rails s`, this errors:

```
.../activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:260:in `resolve_symbol_connection':
'development' database is not configured. Available: ["defaults", "main"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

And [the docs on DB configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) don't have an answer.

Comment: Add an anchor to main, e.g. `main: &main` and configure them as `development: *main`, `test: *main` and `production: *main`. Or use `<<: *main` like you did in main to incorporate defaults.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks Stefan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an anchor to `main`, e.g. `&main`:

```yaml
main: &main
  <<: *defaults
  url: <%= ENV['MAIN_DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['MAIN_DATABASE_POOL'] %>
```

You can use it to define your environments:

```yaml
development: *main
test: *main
production: *main
```

or, just like you did with `defaults`:

```yaml
development:
  <<: *main

test:
  <<: *main

production:
  <<: *main
```

The latter allows you to add additional key-value pairs or to override existing ones.